# send console output to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg, console, window

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 c++ to develop some custom direct show filters. I'm using ffmpeg for the encoding process and if I run tests as a standard console then any ffmpeg errors are displayed in the console window, as one might expect. However the main application is a windows app which doesnt have a console window. When I get errors from ffmpeg all I can use is a fairly generic error return number and it would be great to see what would have been displayed in the console window.

Is it possible to get the output from ffmpeg of what would go to a console window to display in one of the 'Studio output windows. I've ticked the 'Redirect all output window text to the immediate window' option in Tools->Options->Debugging->General but this doesn't like the correct option and it doesn't work anyway.

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect ffmpeg output using custom output routine:

```
av_log_set_callback(&FfmpegLog);

void FfmpegLog(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vl)
{
    static char message[8192];
    const char *module = NULL;

    if (ptr)
    {
        AVClass *avc = *(AVClass**) ptr;
        if (avc->item_name)
            module = avc->item_name(ptr);
    }
    vsnprintf_s(message, sizeof message, sizeof message, fmt, vl);
    std::cout << "[ffmpeg][" << (module ? module : "") << "][" << level << "] : " << message;
}
```

Comment: The handy callback allows me to redirect the output where I need it. Many thanks!